# MySQL update every single row from a 3 million row table

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Requirements: I have to scan the whole table and update every single record, period.

As suggested by other people, I should create a temporary table with identical schema with the original one and do insertion on updated values, then rename table instead of updating on original one.

The idea is something like this:

```
ResultSet row = select * from old_table;
While row.next
  do something to update values in this row
  insert updated values in to a identical table (different name of course)
endWhile
```

The question here is I am using Java JDBC, and I have to deal with ResultSet object. So is there a way to prevent **"ResultSet row = select * from old_table"** generate a out of memory exception?

A potential solution is to paging, but that means I have to use ORDER BY and LIMIT, which can be very slow on a 3 millions rows table.

Is there some trick with ResultSet, like specifying some of the flags like FOWARD_ONLY | NON-SCROLLABLE, etc. Or does Mysql server have some configuration to do smart things like somehow mysql understands that I am doing a full table scan, so just sequentially return records for me, but not all at once.

Any suggestion is welcomed

[UPDATE] seems like MySQL connector/J has  configuration parameter called `useCursorFetch`, if set to true then `statement.setFetchSize(1000)` will work. Not sure if this is the ultimate solution or not.

Comment: It would help if you gave some idea of what the update involves. If the updates are relatively straightforward and you're using MySQL you might do well to look at `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: Thx Mike, it is non-trivial update, involves length operation : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a JDBC statement to non-buffered this way:

```
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

But I would also suggest tying to use an `INSERT... SELECT` statement, so you don't have to use a while loop and don't have to fetch anything.  If you can use SQL expressions for your step of "do something to update values" then you can do the whole operation in one SQL statement.

PS: You'll have to be more specific about QuerySet.  I find multiple classes called QuerySet in different libraries, e.g. org.dbunit.ant.QuerySet, org.gusdb.wdk.model.QuerySet, etc.

Comment: Mysql connector/J driver and java.sql.QuerySet

Comment: Sorry, no class by that name appears in MySQL Connector/J 5.1.25 (I just grepped the source), nor in J2SE 7.  Where are you getting that class from?

Comment: I have this at the top of my import statement: import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet};

Comment: @baboonWorksFine ResultSet != QuerySet.

Comment: Right, if you're using java.sql.ResultSet, then my answer stands.